# Issue with Does not equal statement

Tags: sql

I keep getting "syntax error in query expression" messages.  I have a table full of values where ItemNbr is made up of cells with #s/values and blank(no value) cells.  I want the statement to return results where item number will not be a blank.

My statement is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRUSPWK.SKN AS ItemNbr, TRUSPWK.SKNDESC AS ItemDesc1, TRUSPWK.EANUPC AS UPC, TRUSPWK.VNDRNAME AS VendName, TRUSPWK.VNDRNO AS VendStkNbr
FROM TRUSPWK
WHERE TRUSPWK.SKN <>";
```

The problem I'm noticing is the where statement: TRUSPWK.SKN <>";
Are the <> & " signs being misappropriately used?

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: Notice, that empty string and null value are quite different things.

Comment: Are you sure it is **blank**? Blank must be inserted, instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
WHERE TRUSPWK.SKN <>";
```

To

```
WHERE TRUSPWK.SKN <> '';
```